# Is it possible to call http API by websocket?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I was asked me to make an api call using websocket with php Ratchet at work. Since I'm totally unfamilier with websocket so I googled and watched youtube videos to solve this problem, but The more I searched, the more I felt it is impossible to call api with websocket.

Am I missing something or is it really impossible to call api by websocket?
If it is possible, can you please show me an example how to do it

I know i might sound awkward since I don't have a solid understanding of websockets, English isn't even my first language, but i'm really desperate please help me

Comment: What API? You can’t call an HTTP API from web socket. You can call a web socket API from a web socket. That mostly means you send some specific message over web socket to the server, and the server sends something specific back.

Comment: Its not really clear what you are actually being asked to do, can you have another go at a description

Comment: @RiggsFolly for example i am trying to call https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais-api-services/documentation/api-service:ps04
this api by websocket

Comment: @deceze so you mean there is web socket API that can be used for web socket instead of HTTP API?

Comment: You will have some controling PHP code I assume, call the API as normal, then I assume you want to distribute the result via the websocket. Both bits can exist in the same code, but you are not using the websocket to call the AIS API

Comment: Yes, HTTP APIs are fundamentally different from web socket APIs. That AIS seems to offer an HTTP API. Why are you hoping to be able to call from via web sockets?

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually I was instructed to use web sockets to improve the performance of code that calls multiple APIs. still, your answer was helpful! thanks for answering

Comment: @deceze I was calling several HTTP API using php curl, and my boss wants to improve performance with asynchronous processing using web sockets. So I thought he ment to call APIs by web socket.

Comment: He probably meant to make several HTTP calls in parallel, instead of one after the other. But we're just guessing here…

Comment: @deceze Then I guess I gotta talk to my boss about this... thank you for your effort, it was so helpful! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A REST API is fundamentally different from a WebSocket API.

### REST API

Calls are made through HTTP(S). You can use AJAX (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to access HTTP endpoints directly from the browser. In JavaScript you would use the Fetch-API (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make calls. Each and every call is stateless per definition. Cookies and special headers must be send with every request to create a context (e.g. user that is logged in).

Example (Client):

```js
fetch('http://example.com/my-rest-api/endpoint1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Example (Server):

```js
app.get('/my-rest-api/endpoint1', handlerFunc);
```

### WebSocket API

A stateful connection must be established between a client and a server. The client and server can exchange messages via the connection. Unlike a REST-API messages can be send bidirectional.
A high-level implementation of the WebSocket API is Socket.io.
An API can be designed by defining message types with payloads.
I also would not recommend to use PHP for a WS-API (even though there is a solution like Ratchet). Use a language/runtime that was developed for event-based use cases like this (e.g. nodeJS).

Example (Client):

```js
const socket = SocketClass('example.com/my-websocket-api');

// variant 1 with callbacks
const response = socket.sendMessage('endpoint1', myData);

// variant 2 with message listener
socket.on('endpoint1Response', handlerFunc);
socket.sendMessage('endpoint1', myData);
```

Example (Server):

```js
const serverSocket = SocketClass('/my-websocket-api');
serverSocket.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // variant 1 with callbacks
    socket.on('endpoint1', (data, callback) => {
        callback(null, responseData);
    });

    // variant 2 with message listener
    socket.on('endpoint1', (data, cb) => {
        socket.emit('endpoint1Answer', responseData);
    });
});
```